# Iterating a function over a list

Tags: r

I have a list of dataframes that I want to split along a variable. I am trying to automate this process by creating a function. I know there is a function called split that does this but I'm trying to learn how to create functions so I am using this as practice.

Here is some sample data:

```
Area <- c(1, 5, 5 ,7, 2) 
Protected <- c('protected', 'protected', 'protected', 'unprotected', 'unprotected')
a_data <- data.frame(Area, Protected)

Area <- c(6, 2, 7, 2, 9)
Protected <- c('protected', 'protected', 'protected', 'unprotected', 'unprotected')
b_data <- data.frame(Area, Protected)
```

I want to split each of these along the variable 'Protected' leaving me with four dataframes p_a, p_b, u_a and u_b.

My code so far is this:

```
names <- list('a', 'b')

f <- function(x){
  for(i in names){
    d <- paste(i,'_data', sep = '')
    p_'i' <- subset(d, Protected == 'protected')
    u_'i' <- subset(d, Protected == 'unprotected')
  }
}
```

This doesn't run, I'm pretty sure it is because I am trying to assign the current iteration of i to the name of the variable whilst also trying to assign values to it.

How to I fix this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An idea that slightly changes your function is to put the data frames in a list and iterate directly, i.e.

```
lapply(list(a_data, b_data), function(i) { d1 <- subset(i, Protected == 'protected');
                                           d2 <- subset(i, Protected == 'unprotected'); 
                                           return(list(d1, d2))})
```

which gives,

> ```
> [[1]]
> [[1]][[1]]
>   Area Protected
> 1    1 protected
> 2    5 protected
> 3    5 protected
>
> [[1]][[2]]
>   Area   Protected
> 4    7 unprotected
> 5    2 unprotected
>
>
> [[2]]
> [[2]][[1]]
>   Area Protected
> 1    6 protected
> 2    2 protected
> 3    7 protected
>
> [[2]][[2]]
>   Area   Protected
> 4    2 unprotected
> 5    9 unprotected
> ```

Comment: Thank you! rather than writing out the list all the data frames in the function I have created the list using a for loop. However, when I use this list the function returns NA values for everything. The list still comprises 'a_data' and 'b_data'. do you know what the issue is here?

Comment: what is the structure of your list? (`str(your_list)`)

Comment: Apologies, I have figured that out now it was because I hadn't assigned the dataframe to the items in the list so there was no data for the function to work with! One final question: The actual data involes 100,000's of points, I am therefore reluctant to print all the results into the console. What can I add to the bottom of the function to replace return that would add idividual dataframes for each iteration of d1 and d2?

Comment: You can't omit `return`. What you can do to avoid printing is to assign it, i.e. `final_list <- lapply(...)`. Now you have it saved in `final_list` in your global environment

Answer (score 1):

Here is an option with `bind_rows` and `split`

```
library(dplyr)
bind_rows(a_data, b_data, .id = 'ind') %>% 
      split(list(.$ind, .$Protected))
```